# mean value theorem problem with no equation. Only given average velocity.

Tags: calculus

I have a question that states a person traveled continuously for $4$ hours and a total of $224$ miles, making the average speed $56$ mph. Prove that the car was traveling exactly the average speed of $56$ mph in at least one instant.

How can I prove this?

Comment: Hint: argue by contradiction.

Comment: The mean value theorem states (roughly) that if $f$ is differentiable on some interval, then there exists a point in that interval where the instantaneous rate of change (i.e. the derivative, e.g. the instantaneous velocity) is exactly equal to the average rate of change (e.g. the average velocity).  Notice that your average rate of change over the four hour period in question is 56 mph.

Comment: To have an average speed 56 the car had to either travel with constant speed, or sometimes go slower and sometimes faster. In the latter case, since the acceleration is continuous, it had to have the speed 56 at some point to go from below that to the above that

Comment: so my answer should just state that the instantaneous rate of change must equal the average velocity at some point in accordance with the mean value theorem? I was given no equation for the function. so its impossible to plug in any values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s(t)$ the distance at the time $t$, $t\in [0\text{hr}, 4\text{hr}]$. From physics, we know that the velocity is given by: $v(t)=s'(t)$. Also, $s(0\text{hr})=0\text{mi}$ and $s(4\text{hr})=224\text{mi}$.

Now, apply the mean value theorem to the interval above: we must have $t_0\in [0\text{hr}, 4\text{hr}]$ such that:

$$v(t_0)=s'(t_0)=\frac{s(4\text{hr})-s(0\text{hr})}{4\text{hr}-0\text{hr}}=\frac{224\text{mi}-0\text{mi}}{4\text{hr}-0\text{hr}}=\frac{224\text{mi}}{4\text{hr}}=56\text{mph}$$

so the velocity (and speed) at $t_0$ was $56\text{mph}$, as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

First, suppose the car starts with a speed less than $56$ mph. Then, suppose for a contradiction that there is no instant such that average speed of the car is $56$ mph. Notice that it travels continuously, so this is not possible because it has an average speed of $56$ mph and you cannot have that average with values all of which are less than $56$. So we have a contradiction as required and car has $56$ mph speed at some instant.

Can you do the same for the case where car starts with a speed larger than $56$ mph?

Comment: Oh i completely understand that, but i was asked to PROVE that it traveled at 56 mph in one instant. but without any equation of the function, all i can do is quote the mean value theorem...

Comment: Yes, and this is a proof by contradiction. But if you want to use a theorem, I *Intermediate Value Theorem* may also be useful in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This answer requires that you can prove the following.

If $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and $f(a) < 0 < f(b)$, then there is some number $x$ in $[a, b]$ with $f(x) = 0$.

The car must have traveled either faster or slower than the average speed during its trip, or it would have only traveled at the average speed. Because the speed of the car is continuous, it must have taken on every value between its bounds, including the average speed.

Answer (score 0):

For fun:

Assume the speed is a continuos function of time, I.e. from 58mph it cannot jump to 54 mph (say) abruptly .

Assume the statement is false.

Means : There is no point in time such that the speed was 56 mph.

Then it was greater or less than 56 mph all the time.

(You need continuity here) .

1) If it was always faster than 56 mph you get there faster.

2) Similar argument for slower than 56 mph, more  time .